# How to select all table columns using Ctrl+A in a html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can we select all table td by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> button using jQuery or javascript?

Comment: what do you understand by "selecting" the td ? Add some visual effects for the user or select it in jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and you are gonna have to do it programmatically.

Here is an example: [Handling Keybord Shortcuts in Javascript](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/)

And yes, this **is** a good question.

Comment: but it selects all the text on the page also. This should not happen

Comment: That's why I said you are gonna have to do it programmatically.

Comment: I think the question gets at a useful notion, but it's unclear (especially the ambiguity between JQuery selection and browser selection).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97)) {
        selectText('copyme');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This function will work in Firefox and Chrome. The old version used `keypress()` function and `e.charCode` and didn't work in newer version of Chrome.

The only issue is with selecting text. I've borrowed the function `selectText()` from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/446792

Here is a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function selectText(element) {
        var doc = document;
        var text = doc.getElementById(element);

        if (doc.body.createTextRange) { // ms
            var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) { // moz, opera, webkit
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            var range = doc.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }

    $("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97)) {
            selectText('copyme');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
table, td {
border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent iaculis lobortis adipiscing. Donec consequat commodo posuere. Praesent magna orci, suscipit ut facilisis sed, volutpat in lorem. Nulla eleifend.</p>
<table id="copyme">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
</table>
<p>Vestibulum ac commodo libero. Aenean vitae magna nulla. Vivamus hendrerit, orci sed pretium aliquam.</p>
```

Comment: @Kon I've updated code for Chrome. It worked 5 years ago... :)